# How to concat a StringType column with every element of an ArrayType column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a StringType() column and an ArrayType(StringType()) column in a pyspark dataframe. I want to concat the StringType() column with every element of the ArrayType(StringType()) column.
Example:

```
+-----+---------------------+------------------------------+
|col1 |col2                 |col3                          |
+-----+---------------------+------------------------------+
|'AQQ'|['ABC', 'DEF']       |['AQQABC', 'AQQDEF']          |
|'APP'|['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']|['APPABC', 'APPDEF', 'APPGHI']|
+-----+---------------------+------------------------------+
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for spark 2.4+, use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr 

df = spark.createDataFrame([('AQQ', ['ABC', 'DEF']),('APP', ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])], ['col1', 'col2'])

df.withColumn('col3', expr("transform(col2, x -> concat(col1, x))")).show(truncate=False)                            
+----+---------------+------------------------+
|col1|col2           |col3                    |
+----+---------------+------------------------+
|AQQ |[ABC, DEF]     |[AQQABC, AQQDEF]        |
|APP |[ABC, DEF, GHI]|[APPABC, APPDEF, APPGHI]|
+----+---------------+------------------------+
```